# Bidirectional communication beetwen C# code and unmanaged C++ lib

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, unmanaged

I want use C++ lib with unmanaged code from C#. I found on stackoverflow a few post how do it. In this way it works, but I need some solution to define abstract function from C++ class in C# code (to be specific - my library C++ functions have to call function in C#).

regards
Kamil

Answer (score 3):

Cool question. To get the idea you should consider the following general case. You have a large C++ project and you want to extend it with script. In your case the "script" is the .NET/CLR.

You have:

```
namespace Native {

class NativeInterface
{
public:
    /// Yes, no implementation here, in the "native world"
    virtual void NativeMethod() = 0;

    /// Some other method(s) you'd like to call
    virtual void ConcreteMethod() { cout << "Hello" << endl; }
};

} // namespace Native
```

You must make the C++/CLI wrapper for the Native::NativeInfterface:

```
namespace Managed
{
    ref class NativeInterface
    {
    public:
       virtual void NativeMethod() abstract;

       virtual void ConcreteMethod() { NativeObj->ConcreteMethod(); }
    public:
       Native::NativeInterface* NativeObj;
    };
} /// namespace managed
```

You want to do in C#:

```
namespace Managed {

public class MyNETImplementation: NativeInterface
{
    override void NativeMethod()
    {
       DoTheStuff_UsingNativeCode(); // possibly, call the ConcreteMethod
    }
}

} // namespace Managed
```

and the crucial thing is that you want to pass the "pointer" to MyNETImplementation somewhere to the native world.

So you should implement the tricky NativeInterfaceImpl class in C++/CLI which will hold the managed reference to MyNETImplementation and it will call the appropriate methods.

First try:

```
namespace Managed {

/// C++/CLI in mixed-mode assembly
class NativeInterfaceImpl: public NativeInterface
{
public:
   NativeInterfaceImpl(Managed::NativeInterface^ Obj) { ManagedObj = Obj; }

   /// Native implementation to call the managed class
   virtual void NativeMethod()
   {
      Obj->NativeMethod();
   }
public:
   gcroot<Managed::NativeInterface^> ManagedObj;
};

} // namespace Managed
```

Yes, this is tricky and there are many questions on how to pass the parameters, but the marshaling questions are considered in details on this site.

Forgot to add how to use the managed pointers to NativeInterfaceImpl. You have to "pin" them before usage if they were allocated with the "gcnew" keyword.

```
Managed::NativeInterface^ obj = gcnew NativeInterfaceImpl( gcnew MyNETImplementation() );
pin_ptr<NativeInterface> pinned = obj;

/// void SomeNativeFunction(NativeInterface*);
SomeNativeFunction( pinned );
```

EDIT (Finishing touches):

There are a couple of references, which are slightly outdated (they are related to Managed C++, not C++/CLI), but still easily adaptable.

[Calling managed code from unmanaged](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3906/Unmanaged-to-Managed-Calls)

[Second version of managed<->unmanaged calls](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9903/Calling-Managed-Code-from-Unmanaged-Code-and-vice)

Comment: Yes, make a C++/CLI bridge :=)

Comment: Looks like it is way too hard to be in FAQ :) But it seems OK and it works fine.

Comment: Viktor thanks for your answer. I'm trying use your proposal, but I've one question. I suppose that the last source of code (where you used gcnew) should be implement in C# part. But in C# I can't use gcnet and pointers like ^. Could you tell me if I understood you correctly?

Comment: No, the "gcnew" stuff is a C++/CLI construction. You have to write the "factory method" in C++/CLI and use it from C#. The '^' symbol is a reference (garbage collected object). In C# any instance of a class _is_ a "ref class" in C++/CLI terms. So in C# you just live with the "new". Managed.NativeInterface obj = new NativeInterfaceImpl( new MyNETInterfaceImpl()). Got it ?

Answer (score 0):

> to be specific - my library C++ functions have to call function in C#).

This is totally ok, turn in the function pointers, BUT...

> but I need some solution to define abstract function from C++ class in C#

NO WAY. All you can do is implement interop iwith dll's - not with "compiler artifacts" that are not even standardized (vary between compilers).

Sit down, learn C++, subclass in C++- this CAN be managed C++ (these days C++/CLR) so you can from there call nicely into managed code.

But no, you can not subclass classes stored in a C++ compiler ".lib" artefact in .NET.

Comment: you can, but this is tricky. Recall the UnrealScript from UnrealEngine. You _can_ define classes in script language and those classes can be derived from C++'s classes. The same with .NET(C++/CLI, C#) and "native" C++. This _is_ hard, but see my question for the "workaround".

Comment: THe way I understood the question is class inheritance, not "fake class" a.k.a. interface implementation. This may work, but otherwise - that is way too dirty to debug.

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer because you got right and I got it right also :) Of course, the direct mixing of managed/unmanaged code (in terms of inheritance) is not possible, but I believe this "bridge" to the managed world is what the OP wants. I did this with the scripting languages and I did a lot of interop with .NET, so here was my workaround.